# Removing authentication for a particular file in ubuntu

Tags: file, ubuntu

Whenever I am opening a file for which content is written by a server, I am prompted with authentication. As I had to open many times, would like to remove the authentication. Can someone tell me how to remove the authentication ?

Comment: give permissions using `chmod` command

Comment: I tried 'sudo chmod -R 777' . Didn't work

Answer (score -1):

In /etc/passwd file,
contains settings in below format

login name:optional encrypted password:numerical user ID:numerical group ID:user name or comment field:user home directory:optional user command interpreter

second parameter i.e, **'optional encrypted password'** setting will trigger the authentication

If this parameter is left empty, ubuntu will not prompt for authentication.